# FANN under Python is acting strangely. Is this because I'm using it wrong, or because of the limitations of the tool?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, fann

I have a number of records where I am trying to predict one field based on other fields. I set up a FANN neural net under Python, with ~10 inputs, 100 hidden nodes, and 2 outputs.

When I went to build the nets, with 1000+ records, they went down within a few thousand epochs to an error of about 60, but didn't go down any further; often the error reported was identical down to the last digit from the previous error.

When I went to test it out, I was expecting a weak correlation, but it predicted identical results for each piece of test data.

Now is this behavior because I'm not using FANN correctly (I hope), or because I'm working in a problem space where FANN is not particularly helpful?

ATdhvaankcse,

Comment: Sounds like you overfitted on the test data. Trained for too long/put the threshold too low. Also I think that 100 hidden nodes is very much  considering your number of inputs and training set size.

Comment: Please describe how many possible answers exist, or if continuous the range of possible answers, and how you have mapped the two outputs to them.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be an additional n in "ATdhvaankcse"?